Hazelcast User Code Namespaces Bucket Configuration with only Cloud Providers
We are trying out Hazelcast Operator 5.13 and want to use the User Code Namespace Feature with a Bucket Configuration. But there are only 3 Cloud Providers available and this is not really the way to go for Financial Institutes in Europe (Switzerland).
Is there another way to configure a Bucket Config for Hazelcast Operator?
And if so, how?
In other words how to get rid of "amazonaws.com" in : https://.s3..amazonaws.com
Thanks & Regards
René
